# Pandas Dataframe: Accessing via composite index created by groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, multi-index

I want to calculate a group specific ratio gathered from two datasets.
The two Dataframes are read from a database with

```
leases = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)
sales = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)
```

one for real estate offered for sale, the other for rented objects.
Then I group both of them by their city and the category I'm interested in:

```
leasegroups = leases.groupby(['IDconjugate', "city"])
salegroups = sales.groupby(['IDconjugate', "city"])
```

Now I want to know the ratio between the cheapest rental object per category and city and the most expensively sold object to obtain a lower bound for possible return:

```
minlease = leasegroups['price'].min()
maxsale = salegroups['price'].max()
ratios =  minlease*12/maxsale
```

I get an output like: Category - City: Ratio
But I cannot access the ratio object by city nor category. I tried creating a new dataframe with:

```
newframe = pd.DataFrame({"Minleases" : minlease,"Maxsales" : maxsale,"Ratios" : ratios})
newframe = newframe.loc[newframe['Ratios'].notnull()]
```

which gives me the correct rows, and newframe.index returns the groups.

index.name gives *['IDconjugate', 'city']* but indexing results in a *KeyError*. How can I make an index out of the different groups: ID0+city1, ID0+city2 etc... ?

EDIT:
The output looks like this:

> ```
>                                Maxsales  Minleases    Ratios
> IDconjugate city
> 1           argeles gazost        59500        337  0.067966
>             chelles              129000        519  0.048279
>             enghien-les-bains    143000        696  0.058406
>             esbly                117990        495  0.050343
>             foix                  58000        350  0.072414
> ```

The goal was to select the top ratios and plot them with bokeh, which takes a
dataframe object and plots a column versus an index as I understand it:

```
topselect = ratio.loc[ratio["Ratios"] > ratio["Ratios"].quantile(quant)] 

dots = Dot(topselect, values='Ratios', label=topselect.index, tools=[hover,],
               title="{}% best minimal Lease/Sale Ratios per City and Group".format(topperc*100), width=600)
```

I really only needed the index as a list in the original order, so the following worked:

```
ids = []
cities = []
for l in topselect.index:
    ids.append(str(int(l[0])))
    cities.append(l[1])

newind = [i+"_"+j for i,j in zip(ids, cities)]
topselect.index = newind
```

Now the plot shows 1_city1 ... 1_city2 ... n_cityX on the x-axis. But I figure there must be some obvious way inside the pandas framework that I'm missing.

Comment: example datasets and desired output would help here

Comment: Are you using the correct types for the index?  type(ratio.index[0][0]) and type(ratio.index[0][1])?

Comment: I get it now: everything works fine, when I check for float value: ratios.loc[ratios.index[0][0] == 1.0]